# Как сдлеать блоки с float одиноковой высоту в родителе

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, sass

Блоки разной высоты, хотя высота задана height: 100%

```css
header 
 width: 100%
 background-color: $accent
 .slider 
  width: 100%
  overflow-x: hidden
  .slider_line
   position: relative
   left: 0
   top: 0
   overflow: hidden
   width: 100%
   height: 100%
   transition: left 0.5s
   .slider_slide
    width: 33.33333%
    padding: 100px
    height: 100%
    background-color: #1c1c1c
    float: left
    &:nth-child(1)
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #0f2652 0%, #571557 100%)
    &:nth-child(2)
     background: radial-gradient(to bottom, #571557 0%, #0f2652 100%)
    &:nth-child(3)
     background: linear-gradient(to left, #0f2652 0%, #571557 100%)
```

```html
 <header>
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slider_line clearfix">
   <div class="slider_slide">
    <h2>Text #1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo itaque, qui odit aut aspernatur.         Deleniti ea vitae esse numquam nihil, commodi magnam, harum, iure, eos non architecto veritatis             facere a.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="slider_slide">
    <h2>Text #2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A iure mollitia magnam provident nihil, molestias quis nulla error? In atque nemo odit dolorem culpa perferendis maxime nulla consectetur sit dignissimos.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="slider_slide">
    <h2>Text #3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati architecto reiciendis porro quis. Illo molestias numquam in quas cupiditate, sint. Ex a nostrum veniam, pariatur reprehenderit harum mollitia provident nemo.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </header>
```

```css
@font-face{font-family:roboto-example;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;src:url(../fonts/RobotoRegular/RobotoRegular.eot);src:url(../fonts/RobotoRegular/RobotoRegular.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../fonts/RobotoRegular/RobotoRegular.woff) format("woff"),url(../fonts/RobotoRegular/RobotoRegular.ttf) format("truetype")}@font-face{font-family:roboto-example;font-weight:700;font-style:normal;src:url(../fonts/RobotoBold/RobotoBold.eot);src:url(../fonts/RobotoBold/RobotoBold.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../fonts/RobotoBold/RobotoBold.woff) format("woff"),url(../fonts/RobotoBold/RobotoBold.ttf) format("truetype")}html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background-color:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:700}dfn{font-style:italic}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-.5em}sub{bottom:-.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}pre{overflow:auto}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}input{line-height:normal}input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}input[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto}optgroup{font-weight:700}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0}*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}:after,:before{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}html{font-size:10px;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}body{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#333;background-color:#fff}button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}a{color:#337ab7;text-decoration:none}a:focus,a:hover{color:#23527c;text-decoration:underline}a:focus{outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px}figure{margin:0}img{vertical-align:middle}.img-responsive{display:block;max-width:100%;height:auto}.img-rounded{-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px}.img-thumbnail{padding:4px;line-height:1.42857143;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ddd;-webkit-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;display:inline-block;max-width:100%;height:auto}.img-circle{-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%}hr{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #eee}.sr-only{position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;margin:-1px;padding:0;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(0,0,0,0);border:0}.sr-only-focusable:active,.sr-only-focusable:focus{position:static;width:auto;height:auto;margin:0;overflow:visible;clip:auto}[role=button]{cursor:pointer}.container{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px}@media (min-width:768px){.container{width:750px}}@media (min-width:992px){.container{width:970px}}@media (min-width:1200px){.container{width:1170px}}.container-fluid{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px}.row{margin-left:-15px;margin-right:-15px}.col-lg-1,.col-lg-10,.col-lg-11,.col-lg-12,.col-lg-2,.col-lg-3,.col-lg-4,.col-lg-5,.col-lg-6,.col-lg-7,.col-lg-8,.col-lg-9,.col-md-1,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-sm-1,.col-sm-10,.col-sm-11,.col-sm-12,.col-sm-2,.col-sm-3,.col-sm-4,.col-sm-5,.col-sm-6,.col-sm-7,.col-sm-8,.col-sm-9,.col-xs-1,.col-xs-10,.col-xs-11,.col-xs-12,.col-xs-2,.col-xs-3,.col-xs-4,.col-xs-5,.col-xs-6,.col-xs-7,.col-xs-8,.col-xs-9{position:relative;min-height:1px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px}.col-xs-1,.col-xs-10,.col-xs-11,.col-xs-12,.col-xs-2,.col-xs-3,.col-xs-4,.col-xs-5,.col-xs-6,.col-xs-7,.col-xs-8,.col-xs-9{float:left}.col-xs-12{width:100%}.col-xs-11{width:91.66666667%}.col-xs-10{width:83.33333333%}.col-xs-9{width:75%}.col-xs-8{width:66.66666667%}.col-xs-7{width:58.33333333%}.col-xs-6{width:50%}.col-xs-5{width:41.66666667%}.col-xs-4{width:33.33333333%}.col-xs-3{width:25%}.col-xs-2{width:16.66666667%}.col-xs-1{width:8.33333333%}.col-xs-pull-12{right:100%}.col-xs-pull-11{right:91.66666667%}.col-xs-pull-10{right:83.33333333%}.col-xs-pull-9{right:75%}.col-xs-pull-8{right:66.66666667%}.col-xs-pull-7{right:58.33333333%}.col-xs-pull-6{right:50%}.col-xs-pull-5{right:41.66666667%}.col-xs-pull-4{right:33.33333333%}.col-xs-pull-3{right:25%}.col-xs-pull-2{right:16.66666667%}.col-xs-pull-1{right:8.33333333%}.col-xs-pull-0{right:auto}.col-xs-push-12{left:100%}.col-xs-push-11{left:91.66666667%}.col-xs-push-10{left:83.33333333%}.col-xs-push-9{left:75%}.col-xs-push-8{left:66.66666667%}.col-xs-push-7{left:58.33333333%}.col-xs-push-6{left:50%}.col-xs-push-5{left:41.66666667%}.col-xs-push-4{left:33.33333333%}.col-xs-push-3{left:25%}.col-xs-push-2{left:16.66666667%}.col-xs-push-1{left:8.33333333%}.col-xs-push-0{left:auto}.col-xs-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-xs-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-xs-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-xs-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-xs-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-0{margin-left:0}@media (min-width:768px){.col-sm-1,.col-sm-10,.col-sm-11,.col-sm-12,.col-sm-2,.col-sm-3,.col-sm-4,.col-sm-5,.col-sm-6,.col-sm-7,.col-sm-8,.col-sm-9{float:left}.col-sm-12{width:100%}.col-sm-11{width:91.66666667%}.col-sm-10{width:83.33333333%}.col-sm-9{width:75%}.col-sm-8{width:66.66666667%}.col-sm-7{width:58.33333333%}.col-sm-6{width:50%}.col-sm-5{width:41.66666667%}.col-sm-4{width:33.33333333%}.col-sm-3{width:25%}.col-sm-2{width:16.66666667%}.col-sm-1{width:8.33333333%}.col-sm-pull-12{right:100%}.col-sm-pull-11{right:91.66666667%}.col-sm-pull-10{right:83.33333333%}.col-sm-pull-9{right:75%}.col-sm-pull-8{right:66.66666667%}.col-sm-pull-7{right:58.33333333%}.col-sm-pull-6{right:50%}.col-sm-pull-5{right:41.66666667%}.col-sm-pull-4{right:33.33333333%}.col-sm-pull-3{right:25%}.col-sm-pull-2{right:16.66666667%}.col-sm-pull-1{right:8.33333333%}.col-sm-pull-0{right:auto}.col-sm-push-12{left:100%}.col-sm-push-11{left:91.66666667%}.col-sm-push-10{left:83.33333333%}.col-sm-push-9{left:75%}.col-sm-push-8{left:66.66666667%}.col-sm-push-7{left:58.33333333%}.col-sm-push-6{left:50%}.col-sm-push-5{left:41.66666667%}.col-sm-push-4{left:33.33333333%}.col-sm-push-3{left:25%}.col-sm-push-2{left:16.66666667%}.col-sm-push-1{left:8.33333333%}.col-sm-push-0{left:auto}.col-sm-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-sm-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-sm-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-sm-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-sm-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-0{margin-left:0}}@media (min-width:992px){.col-md-1,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9{float:left}.col-md-12{width:100%}.col-md-11{width:91.66666667%}.col-md-10{width:83.33333333%}.col-md-9{width:75%}.col-md-8{width:66.66666667%}.col-md-7{width:58.33333333%}.col-md-6{width:50%}.col-md-5{width:41.66666667%}.col-md-4{width:33.33333333%}.col-md-3{width:25%}.col-md-2{width:16.66666667%}.col-md-1{width:8.33333333%}.col-md-pull-12{right:100%}.col-md-pull-11{right:91.66666667%}.col-md-pull-10{right:83.33333333%}.col-md-pull-9{right:75%}.col-md-pull-8{right:66.66666667%}.col-md-pull-7{right:58.33333333%}.col-md-pull-6{right:50%}.col-md-pull-5{right:41.66666667%}.col-md-pull-4{right:33.33333333%}.col-md-pull-3{right:25%}.col-md-pull-2{right:16.66666667%}.col-md-pull-1{right:8.33333333%}.col-md-pull-0{right:auto}.col-md-push-12{left:100%}.col-md-push-11{left:91.66666667%}.col-md-push-10{left:83.33333333%}.col-md-push-9{left:75%}.col-md-push-8{left:66.66666667%}.col-md-push-7{left:58.33333333%}.col-md-push-6{left:50%}.col-md-push-5{left:41.66666667%}.col-md-push-4{left:33.33333333%}.col-md-push-3{left:25%}.col-md-push-2{left:16.66666667%}.col-md-push-1{left:8.33333333%}.col-md-push-0{left:auto}.col-md-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-md-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.col-md-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-md-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-md-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-md-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-md-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-md-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-md-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-md-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-md-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-md-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-md-offset-0{margin-left:0}}@media (min-width:1200px){.col-lg-1,.col-lg-10,.col-lg-11,.col-lg-12,.col-lg-2,.col-lg-3,.col-lg-4,.col-lg-5,.col-lg-6,.col-lg-7,.col-lg-8,.col-lg-9{float:left}.col-lg-12{width:100%}.col-lg-11{width:91.66666667%}.col-lg-10{width:83.33333333%}.col-lg-9{width:75%}.col-lg-8{width:66.66666667%}.col-lg-7{width:58.33333333%}.col-lg-6{width:50%}.col-lg-5{width:41.66666667%}.col-lg-4{width:33.33333333%}.col-lg-3{width:25%}.col-lg-2{width:16.66666667%}.col-lg-1{width:8.33333333%}.col-lg-pull-12{right:100%}.col-lg-pull-11{right:91.66666667%}.col-lg-pull-10{right:83.33333333%}.col-lg-pull-9{right:75%}.col-lg-pull-8{right:66.66666667%}.col-lg-pull-7{right:58.33333333%}.col-lg-pull-6{right:50%}.col-lg-pull-5{right:41.66666667%}.col-lg-pull-4{right:33.33333333%}.col-lg-pull-3{right:25%}.col-lg-pull-2{right:16.66666667%}.col-lg-pull-1{right:8.33333333%}.col-lg-pull-0{right:auto}.col-lg-push-12{left:100%}.col-lg-push-11{left:91.66666667%}.col-lg-push-10{left:83.33333333%}.col-lg-push-9{left:75%}.col-lg-push-8{left:66.66666667%}.col-lg-push-7{left:58.33333333%}.col-lg-push-6{left:50%}.col-lg-push-5{left:41.66666667%}.col-lg-push-4{left:33.33333333%}.col-lg-push-3{left:25%}.col-lg-push-2{left:16.66666667%}.col-lg-push-1{left:8.33333333%}.col-lg-push-0{left:auto}.col-lg-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-lg-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-lg-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-lg-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-lg-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-0{margin-left:0}}.clearfix:after,.clearfix:before,.container-fluid:after,.container-fluid:before,.container:after,.container:before,.row:after,.row:before{content:" ";display:table}.clearfix:after,.container-fluid:after,.container:after,.row:after{clear:both}.center-block{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.pull-right{float:right!important}.pull-left{float:left!important}.hide{display:none!important}.show{display:block!important}.invisible{visibility:hidden}.text-hide{font:0/0 a;color:transparent;text-shadow:none;background-color:transparent;border:0}.hidden{display:none!important}.affix{position:fixed}@-ms-viewport{width:device-width}.visible-lg,.visible-md,.visible-sm,.visible-xs{display:none!important}.visible-lg-block,.visible-lg-inline,.visible-lg-inline-block,.visible-md-block,.visible-md-inline,.visible-md-inline-block,.visible-sm-block,.visible-sm-inline,.visible-sm-inline-block,.visible-xs-block,.visible-xs-inline,.visible-xs-inline-block{display:none!important}@media (max-width:767px){.visible-xs{display:block!important}table.visible-xs{display:table!important}tr.visible-xs{display:table-row!important}td.visible-xs,th.visible-xs{display:table-cell!important}}@media (max-width:767px){.visible-xs-block{display:block!important}}@media (max-width:767px){.visible-xs-inline{display:inline!important}}@media (max-width:767px){.visible-xs-inline-block{display:inline-block!important}}@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.visible-sm{display:block!important}table.visible-sm{display:table!important}tr.visible-sm{display:table-row!important}td.visible-sm,th.visible-sm{display:table-cell!important}}@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.visible-sm-block{display:block!important}}@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.visible-sm-inline{display:inline!important}}@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.visible-sm-inline-block{display:inline-block!important}}@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.visible-md{display:block!important}table.visible-md{display:table!important}tr.visible-md{display:table-row!important}td.visible-md,th.visible-md{display:table-cell!important}}@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.visible-md-block{display:block!important}}@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.visible-md-inline{display:inline!important}}@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.visible-md-inline-block{display:inline-block!important}}@media (min-width:1200px){.visible-lg{display:block!important}table.visible-lg{display:table!important}tr.visible-lg{display:table-row!important}td.visible-lg,th.visible-lg{display:table-cell!important}}@media (min-width:1200px){.visible-lg-block{display:block!important}}@media (min-width:1200px){.visible-lg-inline{display:inline!important}}@media (min-width:1200px){.visible-lg-inline-block{display:inline-block!important}}@media (max-width:767px){.hidden-xs{display:none!important}}@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.hidden-sm{display:none!important}}@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.hidden-md{display:none!important}}@media (min-width:1200px){.hidden-lg{display:none!important}}.visible-print{display:none!important}@media print{.visible-print{display:block!important}table.visible-print{display:table!important}tr.visible-print{display:table-row!important}td.visible-print,th.visible-print{display:table-cell!important}}.visible-print-block{display:none!important}@media print{.visible-print-block{display:block!important}}.visible-print-inline{display:none!important}@media print{.visible-print-inline{display:inline!important}}.visible-print-inline-block{display:none!important}@media print{.visible-print-inline-block{display:inline-block!important}}@media print{.hidden-print{display:none!important}}*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}:after,:before{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#666;opacity:1}:-moz-placeholder{color:#666;opacity:1}::-moz-placeholder{color:#666;opacity:1}:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#666;opacity:1}body input:focus:required:invalid,body textarea:focus:required:invalid{color:#666}body input:required:valid,body textarea:required:valid{color:#666}body,html{height:100%}body{font-size:16px;min-width:320px;position:relative;line-height:1.65;font-family:roboto-example,sans-serif;overflow-x:hidden;opacity:1}li,ul{list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0}#load{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;width:75px;height:75px;border:10px solid #fff;border-top:10px solid #182453;-webkit-border-radius:100%;border-radius:100%;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-webkit-animation:1s loading infinite linear;animation:1s loading infinite linear}header{width:100%;background-color:#1c1c1c}header .slider{width:100%;height:100%;overflow-x:hidden}header .slider .slider_line{position:relative;left:0;top:0;overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%;-webkit-transition:left .5s;-o-transition:left .5s;transition:left .5s}header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide{width:33.33333%;height:100%;padding:100px;background-color:#1c1c1c;float:left}header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide:nth-child(1){background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(#0f2652),to(#571557));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#0f2652 0,#571557 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(left,#0f2652 0,#571557 100%);background:linear-gradient(to right,#0f2652 0,#571557 100%)}header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide:nth-child(2){background:-webkit-radial-gradient(top,#571557 0,#0f2652 100%);background:-o-radial-gradient(top,#571557 0,#0f2652 100%);background:radial-gradient(to bottom,#571557 0,#0f2652 100%)}header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide:nth-child(3){background:-webkit-gradient(linear,right top,left top,from(#0f2652),to(#571557));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(right,#0f2652 0,#571557 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(right,#0f2652 0,#571557 100%);background:linear-gradient(to left,#0f2652 0,#571557 100%)}header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide h2{margin:0;text-align:center;line-height:1.15em;font-size:5em;color:#fff;text-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000}header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide p{text-align:center;font-size:1.65em;color:#fff;text-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000}@media only screen and (max-width:992px){header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide p{font-size:1.15em}}@media only screen and (max-width:768px){header{min-height:400px}header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide{padding:50px}header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide p{text-align:center;font-size:1.075em;color:#fff;text-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000}}@media only screen and (max-width:480px){header{min-height:550px}header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide{padding:35px}header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide h2{font-size:4em}header .slider .slider_line .slider_slide p{text-align:center;font-size:1.25em;color:#fff;text-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000}}@-webkit-keyframes loading{0%{-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(360deg);transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes loading{0%{-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(360deg);transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(360deg)}}
```

```html
 <header>
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slider_line clearfix">
   <div class="slider_slide">
    <h2>Text #1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo itaque, qui odit aut aspernatur. Deleniti ea vitae esse numquam nihil, commodi magnam, harum, iure, eos non architecto veritatis facere a.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="slider_slide">
    <h2>Text #2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A iure mollitia magnam provident nihil, molestias quis nulla error? In atque nemo odit dolorem culpa perferendis maxime nulla consectetur sit dignissimos.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="slider_slide">
    <h2>Text #3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati architecto reiciendis porro quis. Illo molestias numquam in quas cupiditate, sint. Ex a nostrum veniam, pariatur reprehenderit harum mollitia provident nemo.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: а Вы не хотите нормальный css привести, чтобы пример воспроизводился?

Comment: Cделал, как вы просили

Comment: не-а, я просил css для конкретной разметки, а Вы зачем-то вывалили весь файл bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Там в конце скомпилированный sass

Comment: Перед медиа запросами

Answer (score 0):

1.задайте вашему родительскому блоку `.slider_line` фиксированную высоту, например 800px

2.если по каким-то причинам не можете задать фиксом, то без абсолютного позиционирования не обойтись.

```
.slider_line{
  position: relative;
}
.slider_slide{
  position: absolute; 
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```